# CentOS 5.5 php-posix with dependency error php53-common

Tags: php, yum, centos5

I'm having problems installing php-posix. The problem I have, is that I used epel.repo and now I can't work out how to get past this. I'm not great with Redhat & yum.

```
[root@badelivery ~]# yum  install php-posix
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirrors.liquidweb.com
 * base: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: centos.aol.com
 * updates: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
addons                                                                                                  | 1.9 kB     00:00     
base                                                                                                    | 1.1 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                    | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                  | 2.1 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                 | 1.9 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-process.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53-common = 5.3.3-22.el5_10 for package: php53-process
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el5_10 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-common-5.3.3-22.el5_10.x86_64 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> php53-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I used EPEL to get fail2ban running, but what I didn't realise is that it has updated my php packages.

```
[root@badelivery ~]# rpm -qa | grep remi
php-xmlrpc-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-gd-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-mysql-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-pear-1.9.1-6.el5.remi
php-odbc-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
mysql-server-5.1.54-1.el5.remi
php-xml-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-devel-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-snmp-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
mysql-libs-5.1.54-1.el5.remi
mysql-5.1.54-1.el5.remi
php-mcrypt-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
mysql-bench-5.1.54-1.el5.remi
php-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
mysqlclient15-5.0.67-1.el5.remi
php-cli-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-common-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-mbstring-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-imap-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
php-ldap-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
mysql-devel-5.1.54-1.el5.remi
php-pdo-5.3.5-1.el5.remi.1
```

It looks like php-postfix is not available on epel.

If I remove php-common, a lot of dependencies will be removed, which I think will lead to a lot of problems.

Is there way to solve this without a lot of pain. This is a prod server.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you keep mentioning EPEL when you've made it clear the repo at issue is the remi repository.

In this case, the problem is that you got PHP from remi, but you disabled the repository. You will need to re-enable it to install additional packages from it. Edit the `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`.

Comment: thanks! The confusion I have is that I enabled 

rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm 

/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo

I don't recall enabling remi specifically, and there is no evidence 
in /etc/yum.repos.d/